# Regular Expression for our roll number

Tags: regex

Please tell me the regular expression for the following roll number.
My University has a format for roll number like this:

> > 2K13/CSE/101

This is divided into three parts:

1. YEAR

   > > 2k13 **Four characters only: digit, character, 2 digits, respectively.**
2. Department

   > > CSE **characters only, may be more than three, not limited**
3. Roll Number

   > > 43 **digits only, but not more than 3 characters**

## NOTE: these three parts are separated by a forward slash (**/**)

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that this is a regex writing service, where you post a list of your requirements and a code monkey here churns out a regex to meet them. That impression couldn't be more wrong. We're glad to help, but you have to make an effort to solve the question yourself first, include that effort here in your question, and ask a **specific question** about a problem you've encountered See [ask] for more information. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following regex with [start and end anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).

```
/^\d[a-z]\d{2}\/[a-z]{3,}\/\d{1,3}$/i
```

1. `\d[a-z]\d{2}` - Four characters only: digit, character, 2 digits, respectively.
2. `[a-z]{3,}` - characters only, may be more than three, not limited
3. `\d{1,3}` - digits only, but not more than 3 characters

[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/ck8jKo/1)

Comment: should i use the last alphabet i?

Comment: @SikandarAli : it's for ignoring case

Comment: Thank you so much It solved my issue. Thanks **Mr. Pranav C Balan**